# How to set permissions differently from channel to channel for several roles at a bulk?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have 5 text channels and 2 voice channels. And from channel to channel, I want to give those channels permissions for 4 seperate roles.

```
text_channel_name = ['server-gateway', 'chatroom', 'gameplay-map', 'spectator-chat', 'log', 'staff-room']
voice_channel_name = ['player-voicechat','spectator-voicechat']
role_name = ['Mediator', 'Player', 'Ghost', 'Spectator'] # (not including admin role)
```

I want to my channels to be set like this:

| Channel Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| server-gateway | even the ones who first entered can see this channel. |
| chatroom | anyone who has roles can enter this room and have chat here. |
| gameplay-map | anyone with roles can see this, but only ones role with 'Mediator' and 'Player' can write something in here. |
| spectator chat | can only be accessable with someone with 'ghost' and 'spectator' roles |
| log, staff-room | only server admins can access this channel |
| player-voicechat | can only be accessable to ones with 'Mediator' or 'Player' role and admin |
| spectator-voicechat | can only be accessable to ones with 'Ghost' or 'Spectator' role and admin |

How should I set my channel like this on discord.py? and I gave `'Mediator'` role all permissions except manage server and manage roles permission. Will I have to get rid of some permissions to make my plan working?

Edit: Someone recommended using server templates when making new server for my bot, but I don't think it as viable solution in a long run. I want to make my bot to have as little help as possible, so I want my bot to automatically run a setup procedure when entering a new server. And what I left to build is designating permissions for the roles that should be different from channel to channel to work as intended.

I wanted to ask was the format that I can use to designate roles' permissions at a bulk for a channel (lines of codes that works on several channels at once will be best)

Comment: Thanks for the guy who just edited it. I tried to make a table but the 'table' was shown as broken.

Comment: You can manage permissions per channel and role in the server settings, what do you need discord.py for?

Comment: Probably for generating new servers with the exact same settings without having to redo it all by hand.

Comment: @JasonRebeloNeves You can use [server templates](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041033511-Server-Templates) for that. The post does not mention multiple servers though.

Comment: @JonathanFeenstra Jason is right. I was making this to work when the bot enters the brand-new server. I made parts for bot generating channels beforehand and I wanted to set permission for them.

Comment: @Haidus In that case, wouldn't server templates be a simpler solution?

Comment: @JonathanFeenstra Only if I am the only one who would use it. If someone else should use it, I manually have to give him/her the template, and I think it's against my thoughts for making this bot. Hmm, should I edit the question and say about things we said in the comment too?

Comment: @Haidus You can just share the link to the template. That seems like a much more straightforward solution to me, since they are specifically made for this purpose. If you use a bot instead, everyone will have to invite it and give it permission to manage roles and channels. If you still want that though, editing the question for clarification would be a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanFeenstra added some context at my question to better explain my situation

Answer (score 0):

If the set of channels you need is always the same you're most likely looking to create your own set of channels with preset permissions in every guild your bot joins.

Channels are attributes of Guilds so that's where you'll find methods to manage them, take a look at:

[Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild)

[discord.PermissionOverwrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite)

Example from the [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel):

```
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}

channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```

EDIT:
Here's a simple functional example using spectator-chat as indicated in the comment

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Setup(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        perms = discord.Permissions()
        perms.update(read_messages=True)
        names = ['ghost', 'spectator']
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
        for n in names:
            role = await guild.create_role(name=n, permissions=perms)
            overwrites[role] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)

        await guild.create_text_channel('spectator-chat', overwrites=overwrites)
```

Comment: I understand how to change permissions for server. But how should update permissions for multiple roles? Can you show me the way using 'spectator-chat' at the table as an example?

Comment: @Haidus I updated my answer, don't be afraid to check the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions)

Comment: why give guild.me permission that can read all messages? Does this mean that I can read messages to all the servers? How about making administartor role and give it to one who invited the bot?

Comment: guild.me represents your bot Member class in the guild. It can only overwrite permissions on level the user who invited it grants, you should declare which permissions your application will need in the invite link you generate in discord dev portal. The guild.me override in my example allows your bot to see messages in the channel you create, not the whole server. Asking for administrator permissions without specific need for it is bad practice and should be avoided